# match legend colors for two seaborn plots

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, matplotlib, seaborn

I have these three subplots and I need to set the colors of the continents in the legends of the two subplots below top match, i.e. Europe = Blue for both, Asia = Red for both, etc. Is there a way I can do that? I'm using Python, seaborn and Matplotlib. This is my code and the resulting plot:

```
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))


ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
diseases.plot(kind="barh", ax = ax1, width = 0.9, cmap = 'Set1_r')
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(0,251,25))
ax1.set_ylabel('Countries', fontsize = 15)
ax1.legend(fontsize = 12)

ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
sns.barplot(x = smok_fem.female_smokers, y = smok_fem.index , hue='continent', data = smok_fem, ax = ax2,
            dodge = False, palette = 'tab10')
ax2.set_xlabel('Female Smokers', fontsize = 14)
ax2.set_ylabel('Countries', fontsize = 14)
ax2.legend(fontsize = 14, markerscale = 2, facecolor = 'w')

ax3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
sns.barplot(x = smok_mal.male_smokers, y = smok_mal.index , hue='continent', data = smok_mal, ax = ax3, dodge = False,
            palette = 'tab10')
ax3.invert_yaxis()
ax3.invert_xaxis()
ax3.yaxis.tick_right()
ax3.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax3.set_xlabel('Male Smokers', fontsize = 14)
ax3.set_ylabel('Countries', fontsize = 14)
ax3.legend(fontsize = 14, facecolor = 'w')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seaborn also accepts a dictionary as palette. The dictionary would map each hue value (continent in this case) to its color.

Here is an example using test data. Note that you can also write the dictionary as `{'Europe': 'blue', 'Asia': 'red', ....}` to have more control over the coloring.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

continents = ['Europe', 'Asia', 'Africa', 'North America', 'South America', 'Oceania']
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': [*'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'],
                   'continent': np.random.choice(continents, 26),
                   'female_smokers': np.random.uniform(20, 60, 26),
                   'male_smokers': np.random.uniform(20, 60, 26),
                   })
df = df.set_index('country')
smok_fem = df.sort_values('female_smokers')
smok_mal = df.sort_values('male_smokers')

palette_colors = sns.color_palette('tab10')
palette_dict = {continent: color for continent, color in zip(continents, palette_colors)}

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))

ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.barplot(x=smok_fem.female_smokers, y=smok_fem.index, hue='continent', data=smok_fem, ax=ax2,
            dodge=False, palette=palette_dict)
ax2.set_xlabel('Female Smokers', fontsize=14)
ax2.set_ylabel('Countries', fontsize=14)
ax2.legend(fontsize=14, markerscale=2, facecolor='w')

ax3 = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.barplot(x=smok_mal.male_smokers, y=smok_mal.index, hue='continent', data=smok_mal, ax=ax3, dodge=False,
            palette=palette_dict)
ax3.invert_yaxis()
ax3.invert_xaxis()
ax3.yaxis.tick_right()
ax3.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax3.set_xlabel('Male Smokers', fontsize=14)
ax3.set_ylabel('Countries', fontsize=14)
ax3.legend(fontsize=14, facecolor='w')

plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn bar plots with same colors]

Note that the continents appear in the same order as they appeared in the dataframe. Continents that don't appear in the dataframe will not appear in the legend. You can also fix a "hue order" via `hue_order=continents`. In that case all continents will appear in the legend, independent of whether they appear in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks so much for your extremely detailed answer!